# SQL query with INNER JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I am getting the following message when trying to get a specific value in my query

"The specified field could refer to more than one table"

It is pretty clear that I am trying to search something present in more than one table, but how to do this right?

now I have the following code:

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerId, Table1.Address, 
       Table2.CustomerId, Table2.Telephone, 
       Table3.CustomerId, Table3.Notes
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerId=TAble2.CustomerId) 
      INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.CustomerId=Table3.CustomerId
WHERE CustomerId = 0015
```

the last sentence is the problem... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, the field `CustomerId` in the `WHERE` clause `WHERE CustomerId = 0015`, is presented in both the two tables. You have to determine from which table you want to use it from; `table1` or `table2`? for example:

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerId, Table1.Address, 
       Table2.CustomerId, Table2.Telephone, 
       Table3.CustomerId, Table3.Notes
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerId=TAble2.CustomerId) 
      INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.CustomerId=Table3.CustomerId
WHERE table1.CustomerId = 0015
```

Answer (score 4):

You should point what table is `CustomerId` from in the WHERE statement

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerId, Table1.Address, 
       Table2.CustomerId, Table2.Telephone, 
       Table3.CustomerId, Table3.Notes
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerId=TAble2.CustomerId) 
      INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.CustomerId=Table3.CustomerId
WHERE Table1.CustomerId = 0015
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize from which table you need customerId.

```
SELECT Table1.CustomerId, Table1.Address, 
       Table2.CustomerId, Table2.Telephone, 
       Table3.CustomerId, Table3.Notes
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerId=TAble2.CustomerId) 
      INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.CustomerId=Table3.CustomerId
WHERE table1.CustomerId = 0015
```